# XSLT - Remove currency formatting and check if number, otherwise pass as string

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to remove currency formatting from a string, but my problem is that the field sometimes contains currency and sometimes it is a string of text.  So it could be:

$20
123,000.00
$123,000.00
Hello World!

Comment: Is the currency symbol always "$" or can it be a euro, yen, etc?

Comment: It would be more elaborated if you could write required output infront of corresponding strings ..

Answer (score 1):

As a single XPATH test if the string could be evaluated as a number and return boolean:

```
number(translate(.,translate(.,'0123456789.',''),''))
```

You could put it into a template like this to return either a parsed number or nothing:

```
<xsl:template name="getNumber">
    <xsl:param name="stringVal" />
     <!--remove all characters other than number and period, use the result in the outer replace to yield only numbers and period -->
    <xsl:variable name="numVal" select="translate(.,translate(.,'0123456789.',''),'')" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <!--If what is left evaluates as a number, then it's a number! -->
        <xsl:when test="number($numVal)">
            <xsl:value-of select="$numVal"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!--Do nothing-->
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Call the template like this:

```
    <xsl:call-template name="getNumber">
        <xsl:with-param name="stringVal" select="." />
    </xsl:call-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a cleaner answer:

```
<xsl:template name="getNumber">
  <xsl:param name="p_stringVal" />
  <xsl:value-of select="translate($p_stringVal,translate($p_stringVal,'0123456789.',''),'')" />
</xsl:template>
```

Call the template like this (where $input_value = '$555,555.55' for example):

```
<xsl:call-template name="getNumber">
  <xsl:with-param name="p_stringVal" select="$input_value" />
</xsl:call-template>
```